# LDAP Filter for AD accounts

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I want to fetch all the ad user accounts that are not expired and has blank password.

Until now I have used an ldap filter that fetches all the expired accounts:

```
  (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user) (!accountExpires=9223372036854775807) (!accountExpires=0))
```

I need to make a filter that fetches all the unexpired accounts and has a blank password.

Any suggestions what modifications do I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inverting your search?  Hopefully, an LDAP pro should be able to help place the 'bang', it may go like so, I just wrapped your filter in `(!...)` :

```
$filter = '(!(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user) (!accountExpires=9223372036854775807) (!accountExpires=0)))'
$Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter
```

I'm surprised there's no property for 'IsExpired'.  However, you can build the array then filter it by the Expiration date.  Like so:

```
#List of filters, each one is a string, 
#by default use single quotes unless you need to force evaluation.  
#Make sure each property used is in the '-Properties' part or a default property.
  $Filters = 'AccountExpires -eq $True', "AccountExpirationDate -gt $(Get-Date)"
  $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties AccountExpires, AccountExpirationDate
  Foreach ($filter in $filters) {
      $Users = $Users | where $filter
      }
```

I do not know how to find the empty passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query for the value of a password, but you can query for "Password Not Required".

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=32)(|(!accountExpires=*)(accountExpires>=131176944000000000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Net user (name of the user) shows user account details, password is also one of them.

Please check the below link.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/56f0a0d7-3bb3-40f5-87e0-00b1c7789885/what-sets-the-password-required-field-in-the-net-user-command?forum=winserverDS